# Creating an edgelist from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, networking, igraph, edge-list

I am trying to create an edgelist from a data frame that contains events from a match. Each row of the data frame is a kill made onto a player from the enemy team. `Playerid` column indicates the person who killed. Assists indicate which person assisted in this particular kill. IDs 1-5 belong to team 1 and 6-10 to team 2. The first column contains rowIDs.

```
      ASSIST1 ASSIST2 ASSIST2 ASSIST2 PLAYERID 
50       6       8      NA      NA        9
51       7      10       9       8        6
52      10       9      NA      NA        6
53       7       9       8      NA        6
54       6       7       8      NA        9
55       2      NA      NA      NA        1
56       8      NA      NA      NA        9
57       6       7       8      NA        9
58       7      10       8      NA        9
59      NA      NA      NA      NA        4
60       4       3      NA      NA        1
61      10       9       8      NA        7
62       9       8      NA      NA        6
63       7       9       8      NA       10
64       3       2      NA      NA        5
65       7      NA      NA      NA        9
66       7      NA      NA      NA        9
```

What I need, is to convert this into an edgelist that will later be converted into a directed network, so I can calculate indegrees, outdegrees and so on. What is more, I need to know how many interactions there were between each of the players but this should be able to be seen in a valued, directed network. However, I am having a problem with converting this into an edgelist. I tried looking for a solution online, but I couldn't find a similar data set that was converted into an edgelist. I would be very grateful if anybody could help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple wide to long format conversion, plus filtering on `NA`s would do the trick.

```
z <- "      ASSIST1 ASSIST2 ASSIST2 ASSIST2 PLAYERID 
50       6       8      NA      NA        9
51       7      10       9       8        6
52      10       9      NA      NA        6
53       7       9       8      NA        6
54       6       7       8      NA        9
55       2      NA      NA      NA        1
56       8      NA      NA      NA        9
57       6       7       8      NA        9
58       7      10       8      NA        9
59      NA      NA      NA      NA        4
60       4       3      NA      NA        1
61      10       9       8      NA        7
62       9       8      NA      NA        6
63       7       9       8      NA       10
64       3       2      NA      NA        5
65       7      NA      NA      NA        9
66       7      NA      NA      NA        9"
dat <- read.table(text = z)
rownames(dat) <- NULL

elist <- reshape2::melt(dat, id.vars = "PLAYERID")
elist <- elist[!is.na(elist[, 3]), c(1, 3)]
elist <- as.matrix(elist)

library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_edgelist(elist)
plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: The character vector is your posted data to import it into my R session. I've included this bit so you can judge wether I might have made a mistake in data import. You can substitute the `dat` variable in the code by the data you posted. Sorry for the confusion. For future reference, you can also use `dput(my_example_data)` and post the results so that others can reproducibly use the same data.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate on the structure of the character vector? If I take this one match and I use
` babip1 <- as.character(babip[[1]]) `
I receive a character with 5 elements which are "c(1,2,3,etc.)". If I follow with this 
` ebabip1 <- read.table(text = babip1) `
they spread into a wide format but I cannot get rid of NAs since each one of them is followed by a coma and each first cell contains "c(". If I extract let's say the fourth row with 
` as.character(ebabip1[4,]) `
I receive numbers which are different from the original row in the frame.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I've added the data import bit as well as to avoid confusion.

Comment: Oh ok so you copy pasted it just like that. I didn't think about it. I will try to convert the data into a format like this one. Thank you very much for your help.